# javafx graphicscontext.rotate not working

Tags: canvas, javafx

Rest of the code works fine.I just cannot rotate it in rotateCanvas event handler!I can draw on the canvas through mouse events. The fxml layout file has a button which is mapped to rotateCanavas() event handler.This is a code snippet pf my fxml layout controller class.
Please tell me what I'm missing!! Thanks.

```
  public void initialize() {
    try {
        //initializing canvas
        gc = whiteCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();        
        initDraw(gc);

        //event handlers of canvas
        whiteCanvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, 
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(true)
                {
                    lastAction = "START";
                    gc.beginPath();
                    gc.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    gc.stroke();
                    ChatMessage whiteboardMSG = new ChatMessage();
                    whiteboardMSG.setMessageType(MessageConstants.WHITEBOARD);
                    whiteboardMSG.setWhiteboardAction(MessageConstants.START);
                    whiteboardMSG.setPointX(event.getX());
                    whiteboardMSG.setPointY(event.getY());
                    whiteboardMSG.setCurrentStroke(gc.getStroke().toString());
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println(MessageConstants.START);
                        oos.writeObject(whiteboardMSG);
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        //error in sending mouse entered event
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        whiteCanvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(true)
                {
                    if(lastAction == "DRAG")
                    {
                        gc.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        gc.stroke();
                    }
                    if(lastAction == "END")
                    {
                        gc.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        gc.stroke();
                    }
                    if(lastAction == "START")
                    {
                        gc.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        gc.stroke();
                    }

                    lastAction = "DRAG";
                    ChatMessage whiteboardMSG = new ChatMessage();
                    whiteboardMSG.setMessageType(MessageConstants.WHITEBOARD);
                    whiteboardMSG.setWhiteboardAction(MessageConstants.DRAG);
                    whiteboardMSG.setPointX(event.getX());
                    whiteboardMSG.setPointY(event.getY());
                    whiteboardMSG.setCurrentStroke(gc.getStroke().toString());
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println(MessageConstants.DRAG);
                        oos.writeObject(whiteboardMSG);
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        //error in sending mouse entered event
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        whiteCanvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(true)
                {
                    lastAction = "END";
                    ChatMessage whiteboardMSG = new ChatMessage();
                    whiteboardMSG.setMessageType(MessageConstants.WHITEBOARD);
                    whiteboardMSG.setWhiteboardAction(MessageConstants.END);
                     whiteboardMSG.setPointX(event.getX());
                        whiteboardMSG.setPointY(event.getY());
                        whiteboardMSG.setCurrentStroke(gc.getStroke().toString());
                        try
                        {
                            System.out.println(MessageConstants.END);
                            oos.writeObject(whiteboardMSG);
                        }
                        catch(IOException e)
                        {
                            //error in sending mouse entered event
                        }
                }

            }
        });
        //setting image on respective buttons-incomplete
        /*try {
            btnPencil.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/resources/pencil.png');-fx-min-height: 10px; -fx-min-width: 10px;");
            btnZoom.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/resources/zoom.png');-fx-min-height: 10px; -fx-min-width: 10px;");
            btnRotate.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/resources/rotate.png');-fx-min-height: 10px; -fx-min-width: 10px;");
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
          }*/
        //connecting server
        this.userName.setText(ClientMain.controller.getButtonLogin().getText());
        System.out.println(this.userName);
        this.serverIp.setText(ClientMain.controller.getServerId().getText());
        if (serverIp.getText() != null && !serverIp.getText().isEmpty()) {
            this.serverSocket = new Socket(this.serverIp.getText(), 9888);
        } else {
            this.serverIp.setText("Localhost");
            this.serverSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9888);
        }
        this.clientLogs.appendText("Connected to Server :" + serverSocket.getInetAddress() + " Port :"
                + serverSocket.getPort() + "\n");
        this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(this.serverSocket.getInputStream());
        this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(this.serverSocket.getOutputStream());
        RunnableClient runnableClient = new RunnableClient(this, this.serverSocket, ois, oos);
        Thread runnableClientThread = new Thread(runnableClient);
        runnableClientThread.start();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        this.clientLogs.appendText("Unknown host error\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        this.clientLogs.appendText("Internal server error\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        registerClient();
    }

}

private void initDraw(GraphicsContext gc){
    double canvasWidth = gc.getCanvas().getWidth();
    double canvasHeight = gc.getCanvas().getHeight();

    gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    gc.setLineWidth(5);

    gc.fill();
    gc.strokeRect(
            0,              //x of the upper left corner
            0,              //y of the upper left corner
            canvasWidth,    //width of the rectangle
            canvasHeight);  //height of the rectangle

    gc.setFill(Color.RED);
    gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    gc.setLineWidth(1);

}


@FXML
void rotateCanvas(ActionEvent event)
{
    gc.rotate(90);

    System.out.println("rotated");
}
```

fxml layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.InnerShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane id="borderPaneMain" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.unitalk.client.ClientController">
   <bottom>
      <VBox prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="882.0" style="-fx-background-color: #adebad;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="882.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField id="message" fx:id="message" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="433.0" promptText="Enter your message">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="50.0" top="25.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Button id="buttonSend" fx:id="buttonSend" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonSendAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #46d246;" text="Send" textFill="#136e4b">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" top="23.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </bottom>
   <right>
      <VBox prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="113.0" style="-fx-background-color: #adebad;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Text fill="#012c09" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Online Users" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="271.63671875">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <ListView id="userList" fx:id="userList" prefHeight="478.0" prefWidth="252.0">
               <effect>
                  <InnerShadow />
               </effect>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="40.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </ListView>
         </children>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </VBox>
   </right>
   <center>
      <VBox prefHeight="503.0" prefWidth="540.0" style="-fx-background-color: #adebad;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="619.0">
               <children>
                  <Text fill="#928b8b" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Connected:">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <Text id="serverIp" fx:id="serverIp" fill="#033707" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Localhost">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <Text id="textUser" fill="#6b6a6a" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="User:">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="200.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <Text id="userName" fx:id="userName" fill="#0d4a11" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="userName">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <Button id="buttonLogout" fx:id="logoutButton" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonLogoutAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="94.0" style="-fx-background-color: #46d246;" text="Logout" textFill="#136e4b">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="20.0" top="5.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
            <Text id="textGroupChat" fill="#052811" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Chats:" wrappingWidth="613.63671875">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="15.0" top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <HBox prefHeight="272.0" prefWidth="611.0">
               <children>
                  <GridPane>
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnBlack" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPencilColor" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" text="  " />
                        <Button fx:id="btnBlue" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPencilColor" style="-fx-background-color: #0a014d;" text="   " GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnRed" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPencilColor" style="-fx-background-color: #ae030e;" text="   " GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnGreen" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPencilColor" style="-fx-background-color: #3eae40;" text="   " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnYellow" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPencilColor" style="-fx-background-color: #ccff00;" text="   " GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnCyan" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPencilColor" style="-fx-background-color: #00ffcc;" text="   " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnGrey" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPencilColor" style="-fx-background-color: #587e60;" text="   " GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnPurple" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPencilColor" style="-fx-background-color: #977ffa;" text="   " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnClear" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clearCanvas" text="Clear" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnPencil" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPencilTool" text="Pencil OFF" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnRotate" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#rotateCanvas" text="Rotate" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnZoom" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Zoom" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnSave" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <Pane id="canvasPane" fx:id="canvasPane" prefHeight="272.0" prefWidth="540.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;">
                     <children>
                        <Canvas id="whiteCanvas" fx:id="whiteCanvas" height="273.0" width="460.0" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <TextArea id="clientLogs" fx:id="clientLogs" editable="false" prefHeight="166.0" prefWidth="620.0">
               <effect>
                  <InnerShadow />
               </effect>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="15.0" right="7.0" top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextArea>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <opaqueInsets>
      <Insets />
   </opaqueInsets>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: what in specific is the error that it is returning?

Comment: There is no error! gc.rotate(90) does nothing! @TravisF. Thanks

Comment: can you post up the FXML? I would assume the button that you have defined for the rotateCanvas in the FXML is either not working or has an error.

Comment: sys.out in the button event works fine! even though I'll post fxml

Comment: is `gc` defined before your `initialize()`?

Comment: yes @TravisF .its a class variable

Comment: The only thing I can think of is it may be having an issue with the fact that `gc` is initialized within a try, meaning that it is never seen as actually being initialized outside of the try, you can move the beginning of the try to the start of your server connections as you do not need it to be there for Canvas and MouseEvents, this way it is guaranteed to see `gc` as initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GraphicsContext::rotate` affects the drawing *you will draw from now*. See this case,

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
gc.setLineWidth(3.0);
gc.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

gc.rotate(15);
gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
gc.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

gc.rotate(15);
gc.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
gc.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
```

[image]

If you want to rotate *rendered canvas image* (from the center as the pivot), for example:

```
gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
gc.setLineWidth(3.0);
gc.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

Image snapshot = canvas.snapshot(null, null);
gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

gc.save(); // Save default transform
Affine rotate = new Affine();
rotate.appendRotation(90, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);
gc.setTransform(rotate);
gc.drawImage(snapshot, 0, 0);
gc.restore(); // Restore default transform
```

[image]

Try it out please.